# Entity Framework Core Random Items keep getting fetched Inside IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net-core, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2017

I have the following code in C#, .Net Core 2.2, Entity Framework Core 2.2, MS SQL Server 2017:

```
IEnumerable<PostData> topicsData = context.Topics
                    .OrderBy(t => Guid.NewGuid())
                    .Take(3)
                    .Select(t => new PostData()
                    {
                        TopicID = t.TopicID,
                        UserID = t.UserID,
                        User = t.User,
                        MessageID = t.MessageID,
                        Message = t.Message,
                        Replies = t.Replies
                    })
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .AsEnumerable();

List<PostModel> posts = new List<PostModel>();
List<UserModel> users = new List<UserModel>();

foreach (var topic in topicsData)
{
    var postModel = new PostModel()
            {
                id = topic.TopicID,
                userId = topic.UserID,
                message = topic.Message.Content,
                replies = topic.Replies,
            };
    posts.Add(postModel);

    var userModel = new UserModel()
            {
                id = topic.User.UserID,
                username = topic.User.Username
            };

    if (!users.Any(u => u.id == userModel.id)) 
    {
        users.Add(userModel);
    }
}
```

What I basically want to do is fetch a set of 3 random items from Topics table in my db, and map the result into 2 separate lists, one for for the topics themselves (posts) and one for distinct users.

As you see I am taking the 3 random items using the commands:

```
.OrderBy(t => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(3)
```

However, I have a problem: In the first Select where I populate the topicsData object, I get a list of items, and after the foreach loop finishes to run I see a whole other list of items.

When I debug this code, every single line in my foreach loop causes the data in topicsData to be fetched again with a new random set of 3 Topic items.

I don't understand what's wrong. When I used `AsEnumerable()` on my `topicsData` object didn't I get an entirely new separate list of items and stopped working against my DB?

Why does it keep going to the DB and fetching more random items?

And how can I make it stop re-fetching and get fixed on the list of items that it initially fetched?

Comment: Change `.AsEnumerable()` to `.ToList()`.

Comment: Most likely because you have `.AsEnumerable();` .This will be evaluated when needed (in this case when it reaches the for-each). To load the data you want into the memory you will need to `.ToList()` instead of `AsEnumerable();`

Comment: _and after the foreach loop finishes to run I see a whole other list of items_ how you are looking at those items?

Comment: Thank you Fabio and @Noobie you were correct once I changed it to ToList the problem was fixed! I wonder however if it can get this unpredictable - In which cases would we want to use AsEnumerable then?

Comment: @shahaf IEnumerable's execution is deferred which might have some performace gains and it also returns the latest data since as it is actually executed when needed (e.g. for each) In your case you need a final list in order to get 3 random values, otherwire you could keep it as Enumerable. The reason it was keep changing was because in every for each a new guid was generated for each record on the query.